# Create feature based on consecutive rows in various independent sections of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I could not think of a better way to word the question, kindly edit if you have something better.

| date | country | total_cases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | denmark | 2 |
| 2 | denmark | 5 |
| 3 | denmark | 10 |
| 4 | denmark | 17 |
| 1 | usa | 5 |
| 2 | usa | 13 |
| 3 | usa | 23 |
| 4 | usa | 37 |
| 1 | india | 0 |
| 2 | india | 2 |
| 3 | india | 9 |
| 4 | india | 40 |

From the above dataframe, if I want to create a new feature `new_cases`, I can do this-

```
df['new_cases'] = df['total_cases'] - df['total_cases'].shift(1)
```

But that would also find values from where one country ends and another begins. (usa date 1 - denmark date 4). The workaround I have been using is running a loop like this-

```
new_cases = []
for country in df['country'].unique():
    temp_df = df[df['country'] == country]
    temp_array = temp_df['total_cases'] - temp_df['total_cases'].shift(1)
    new_cases.append(temp_array)

df['new_cases'] = pd.concat(temp_array)
```

As you can imagine, this takes time to run when the dataframe is huge, especially when creating multiple such features. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe a pandas function especially for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
df['new_cases'] = df['total_cases'] - df.groupby('country')['total_cases'].shift(1)
```

Or [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df['new_cases'] = df.groupby('country')['total_cases'].diff(1)
```

Comment: Do you think it can work with pivot table as well? Just curious. I tried, but can't seem to get it.

Comment: @callmeanythingyouwant - I think not, 'diff' is not aggregate function